# How to perform feature selection technique using DBSCAN?

Tags: dbscan

I have a small doubt regarding the feature selection using DBSCAN as I am new to this algorithm; I was performing DBSCAN using the scikit-learn package, and I could not understand what this algorithm is doing. The result of this is only noise and clusters I can extract. As most of the references I refer to it does not explain the details of how I can perform feature selection using this DBSCAN.

Comment: DBSCAN is a clustering algorithm, why would you think you can do feature selection with it?

Comment: I was implementing a research paper where the author used DBSCAN to get a subset of features but did not explain how it was performed. So, I was a little stuck in the area.

Comment: Well, I don't know what this author did or how, but as far as I know feature selection is not part of DBSCAN, so it looks to me like the author pulled something out of his/her posterior.

Comment: mind to provide the reference ? by transposing the dataset you can cluster features but that don't explain how he chose features after clustering